# How to feed a column with the concated value of other two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanna create a trigger to feed a column with a concated value from the other two columns.

I imagine it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE table-name
SET column-concated = (SELECT column1, column2, concat(column1, column2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a sub-select:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = concat(column1, column2);
```